# Comparing values in two numpy arrays with 'if'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Im fairly new to numpy arrays and have encountered a problem when comparing one array with another.

I have two arrays, such that:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([2,4,3,5,2])
```

I want to do something like the following:

```
if b > a:
    c = b
else:
    c = a
```

so that I end up with an array c = np.array([2,4,3,5,5]).

This can be otherwise thought of as taking the max value for each element of the two arrays.

However, I am running into the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all().
```

I have tried using these but Im not sure that the are right for what I want.

Is someone able to offer some advice in solving this?

Comment: `numpy.maximum` [take a look at](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html)

Comment: The fundamental thing to understand here is that it is ambiguous to compare 2 arrays as the error suggests, are you wanting to compare all values, what if one value is higher? what if all but one is higher? So you have to specify the criteria for the comparison, for what you are attempting `np.maximum` does what you want, but there are also `any(), all()` attributes also that spell out your criteria so you avoid the error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking for the function `np.fmax`. It takes the element-wise maximum of the two arrays, ignoring NaNs.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([2, 4, 3, 5, 2])
c = np.fmax(a, b)
```

The output is

```
array([2, 4, 3, 5, 5])
```

Answer (score 6):

As with almost everything else in numpy, comparisons are done element-wise, returning a whole array:

```
>>> b > a
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

So, is that true or false? What should an `if` statement do with it?

Numpy's answer is that it shouldn't try to guess, it should just raise an exception.

If you want to consider it true because at least one value is true, use `any`:

```
>>> if np.any(b > a): print('Yes!')
Yes!
```

If you want to consider it false because not all values are true, use `all`:

```
>>> if np.all(b > a): print('Yes!')
```

---

But I'm pretty sure you don't want either of these. You want to broadcast the whole `if`/`else` over the array.

You could of course wrap the `if`/`else` logic for a single value in a function, then explicitly [`vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) it and call it:

```
>>> def mymax(a, b):
...     if b > a:
...         return b
...     else:
...         return a
>>> vmymax = np.vectorize(mymax)
>>> vmymax(a, b)
array([2, 4, 3, 5, 5])
```

This is worth knowing how to do… but very rarely worth doing. There's usually a more indirect way to do it using natively-vectorized functions—and often a more *direct* way, too.

---

One way to do it indirectly is by using the fact that True and False are numerical 1 and 0:

```
>>> (b>a)*b + (b<=a)*a
array([2, 4, 3, 5, 5])
```

This will add the `1*b[i] + 0*a[i]` when `b>a`, and `0*b[i] + 1*a[i]` when `b<=a`. A bit ugly, but not too hard to understand. There are clearer, but more verbose, ways to write this.

But let's look for an even better, direct solution.

---

First, notice that your `mymax` function will do exactly the same as Python's built-in `max`, for 2 values:

```
>>> vmymax = np.vectorize(max)
>>> vmymax(a, b)
array([2, 4, 3, 5, 5])
```

Then consider that for something so useful, numpy probably already has it. And a quick search will turn up [`maximum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
>>> np.maximum(a, b)
array([2, 4, 3, 5, 5])
```

Comment: Great explanation of what I was doing and why it wouldn't work. I can see that I need to treat the array as a whole and not break it up by elements.

Comment: @NathanThomas: Exactly. That's the only tricky bit about numpy: most things just work the obvious way you'd expect, but every once in a while you want to do something that's obviously iterative in your hear, and you have to figure out how to translate it into something element-wise. (There's always `vectorize`—or, when worst comes to worst, `fromiter` around a generator expression—which you can't, but it should rarely if ever come to that.)

Comment: by far the best answer and one that keeps popping up every now and then!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an other way of achieving this

```
c = np.array([y if y>z else z for y,z in zip(a,b)])
```

Comment: One problem of this solution is the result is not of type `numpy.ndarray` as `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

The following methods also work:

1. Use `numpy.maximum`

   `>>> np.maximum(a, b)`
2. Use `numpy.max` and `numpy.vstack`

   `>>> np.max(np.vstack(a, b), axis = 0)`

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most efficient one but this is a more suitable answer to the original question:

```
import numpy as np

c = np.zeros(shape=(5,1))

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([2,4,3,5,2])

for i in range(5):
    if b.item(i) > a.item(i):
        c[i] = b.item(i)
    else:
        c[i] = a.item(i)
```