# How to compare two numpy arrays with multiple condition

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have 2 NumPy arrays like the below

```
array_1 = np.array([1.2, 2.3, -1.0, -0.5]) 
array_2 = np.array([-0.5, 1.3, 2.5, -0.9])
```

We can do the element-wise simple arithmetic calculation (addition, subtraction, division etc) easily using different `np` functions

```
array_sum = np.add(array_1, array_2)
print(array_sum) # [ 0.7  3.6  3.5 -0.4]  

array_sign = np.sign(array_1 * array_2)
print(array_sign) # [-1.  1.  1. -1.]
```

However, I need to check element-wise `multiple conditions` for 2 arrays and want to save them in 2 new arrays (say `X` and `Y`).

For example, if both elements contain `different sign` (e.g.: 1st and 3rd element pairs of the given example)) then, `X` will contain `0` and `Y` will be the `sum` of the `poitive element` and `abs(negative element)`

```
X = [0]
Y = [1.7]
```

When `both` elements are `positive` (e.g.: 2nd element pair of the given example) then, `X` will contain the `lower value` and `Y` will contain the `greater value`

```
X = [1.3]
Y = [2.3]
```

If both elements are `negative`, then, X will be `0` and `Y` will be the `sum` of the `abs(negative element)` and `abs(negative element)`

So, the final `X` and `Y` will be something like

```
X = [0, 1.3, 0, 0]
Y = [1.7, 2.3, 3.5, 1.4]
```

I have gone through some posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760183/comparing-values-in-two-numpy-arrays-with-if), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005152/extract-the-count-of-positive-and-negative-values-from-an-array)) that described, the comparison procedures between 2 arrays, but not getting idea for multiple conditions. Here, 2 arrays are very small but, my real arrays are very large (e.g.: contains `2097152` element per array).

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: To simplify a bit, if EITHER element is negative, then X is `0` and Y is the sum of the abs..  Otherwise, X is min and Y is max.  Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `numpy.select`:

```
conditions = [(array_1>0)&(array_2>0), (array_1<0)&(array_2<0)]
choiceX = [np.minimum(array_1, array_2), np.zeros(len(array_1))]
choiceY = [np.maximum(array_1, array_2), -np.add(array_1,array_2)]

X = np.select(conditions, choiceX)
Y = np.select(conditions, choiceY, np.add(np.abs(array_1), np.abs(array_2)))

>>> X
array([0. , 1.3, 0. , 0. ])

>>> Y
array([1.7, 2.3, 3.5, 1.4])
```

Comment: would you mind giving some hints to get `-min(abs(array_1), abs(array_2))` instead of `0`for the `X`?

Comment: I have used this `-np.minimum(np.abs(array_1), np.abs(array_2))` in `choiceX` instead of `np.zeros(len(array_1))` and as an additional result in the `X` and working for the demo data. If I need to change or I am doing wrong, please, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it.  It does require vertically stacking the two arrays.  I'm sure someone will pipe up if there is a more efficient solution.

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.array([1.2, 2.3, -1.0, -0.5]) 
array_2 = np.array([-0.5, 1.3, 2.5, -0.9]) 

def pick(t):
    if t[0] < 0 or t[1] < 0:
        return (0,abs(t[0])+abs(t[1]))
    return (t.min(), t.max())

print( np.apply_along_axis( pick, 0, np.vstack((array_1,array_2))))
```

Output:

```
[[0.  1.3 0.  0. ]
 [1.7 2.3 3.5 1.4]]
```

The second line of the function can also be written:

```
        return (0,np.abs(t).sum())
```

But since these will only be two-element arrays, I doubt that saves anything at all.

Comment: The `select` answer is almost certainly better, because it spends less time in Python code.